# How to track product-wise payments when using Razorpay?

Tags: wordpress, razorpay

I'm building a WordPress website. There is a page where there are three products. The customer can click any one of them. What are the ways to track which payment is made for which product?

I've looked in documentation and API reference but couldn't find a way for adding a product to payment.

I don't even know if RazorPay provides something for tracking this via the dashboard or I've to build some logic at the WordPress end.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions can be:

Using orders-api from RazorPay, Orders in RazorPay are similar to orders you create on your systems. 
It helps you create orders on which you can retry multiple payments until any one of them succeeds. You can set description for an order, which you can see on the RazorPay dashboard.

Now you don't have to see payments on dashboard, you can just see orders. Also, you can save any metadata for each of your order in 'notes' part of RazorPay order.

Below documentation by RazorPay is helpful for your use case 
https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/orders/